# How to fire Watcher, when newValue is the same String?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, base64, vuejs3, watch

I'm inserting `base64 images` into an editor by assigning their `base64 string` to reactive object `state.image` and pointing a watcher at it. Problem is that when I want to insert the same image twice, the watcher doesn't fire.

**`watcher`**:

```
const renderImage = (editor) => {
    const unwatch = watch(() => state.image, () => {
        console.log('watcher fires!')
        editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: state.image }).run()
        unwatch()
        state.image = null
    })
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to kill the watcher with `unwatch()` and in addition set `state.image = null` but it still doesn't fire when the same image is loaded.

The `@click` event is triggered in this element:

```
<button  @click="$refs.image.click(); renderImage(editor)"></button>

<input type="file" ref="image" style="display: none" @change="getImageUrl">
```

and the `dataUrl` of the image is created in `getImageUrl`:

```
const getImageUrl = (event) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (!files.length)
        return;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        state.image = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
```

Both elements seem to work as desired.

How do I make the watcher fire?

Comment: It's hard to follow what exactly happens here. Possibly `immediate` and/or `flush: 'sync'` watcher options could help.

Comment: @EstusFlask I've investigated and tried `deep: true`, `flush: 'post'` and `flush: 'sync'` options but the watcher never fires when inserting the same image twice. I've also tried using a `getter`, still nothing changed.

Comment: How do you insert the same image?  Did you select the same image by the file input? Do you clear the input value before it? If you select the same file in a file input, the `change` listener will not be fired

Comment: @Duannx the `input field` triggers `@change` the function `getImageUrl`, which creates the `base64` dataurl of the image and assigns it to `state.image`.

Comment: Is the `reader.onload()` fired correctly at the second input? Also, is `files[0]` ever equals to `null`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to watch the `state` and not `state.image`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840974/vue-js-watcher-not-working

Comment: Does the watcher fire and function correctly when two different images are uploaded?

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN yes.

Answer (score 2):

The question assumes the `watch` callback isn't firing, but in this case, it's actually the `<input>` that isn't firing its event.

The `<input>` only fires the `change`/`input` event when its value actually changes. When selecting the same file, the value hasn't changed, and thus no `change`-event occurs to call the `getImageUrl()` handler, which would've triggered the `watch` when the file gets loaded.

To resolve the issue, reset the `<input>`'s value after copying the selected file's path:

```js
⋮
const image = ref() // template ref on input

const getImageUrl = (event) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (!files.length)
        return;

    const fileToRead = files[0]; // 1️⃣ copy input's value
    image.value.value = null;    // 2️⃣ and reset the input
  
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        state.image = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileToRead);
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-trigger-input-change-for-same-file-selection?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FImageButton.vue)

#### Minor refactoring

`renderImage()` is actually just using `watch` to essentially create an async callback for `FileReader`'s `load` event. It seems this could be simplified by moving the image rendering code into that `load`-event handler directly:

```js
const getImageUrl = (event) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (!files.length)
        return;

    const fileToRead = files[0];
    image.value.value = null;

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        //  render image
        editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: event.target.result }).run();
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileToRead);
}
```

Then you could remove `renderImage()`:

```html
<!-- <button @click="$refs.image.click(); renderImage(editor)"></button> --> <!-- no longer needed -->

<button @click="$refs.image.click()"></button>
```

...and also `state.image`:

```js
const state = reactive({
  // image: '' // no longer needed
})
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-trigger-input-change-for-same-file-selection-tinzn7?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FImageButton.vue)